# Can this Sunrace standard gear hanger be used with a quick release axle?

Tags: gears

Can I use a [Sunrace standard gear hanger](https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/gear-spares/sunrace-standard-gear-hanger/) with a quick release axle? The current axle does not protrude enough to extend into the area shown on the picture below which overlaps the frame (and looks like the axle should definitely be long enough for that as per the design of the gear hanger). I was considering changing the axle to a solid one.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be comfortable using a QR rear wheel on such a hanger, with caveats:

- Make sure the QR skewer is long enough to engage all the threads in the acorn nut.
- Put the QR lever on the left side of the bike, away from the cassette.
- That silver bolt visible on the left of your image, should go through to a specially shaped nut on the inside which is curved to sit in the top of the dropout.  That should be a good snug fit in the dropout and prevent the hanger from sliding or rotating without force.
- Your axle should have just enough stickout on the right-hand side to engage with the hanger but not so much it stops the acorn nut from tightening down completely.  Without this, the hanger might rotate a little, throwing shifting off.

Changing to a solid rear axle is a valid solution too.  Just remember to pack a 15mm ring-spanner in your on-bike toolkit.